# can you give me a synonym for " accumulated wisdom"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

who can explain for me what exactly the " accumulated wisdom" mean? I mean in this sentence from a play by Bruce Norris" KELLY : Right. I think the point is, I hope? that the accumulated wisdom of your nineteen years might not be all that comprehensive, Okay?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Experience](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Experience) may be used in the context:

> - accumulated knowledge, esp of practical matters: a man of experience.

In the sentence there is reference to a limited ( not all that comprehensive) experience in life because of the young age ( nineteen years old).